# Access MS Graph Api with Programmed Credentials

Tags: .net, microsoft-graph-api, adal, azure-ad-msal

I am new at using the Graph Api, and I am trying to figure out a way for my web app to be able to access The Graph Api without being asked for a username or password every time by having it programmatically sign-in every startup.

I have an account that I want only to be used in this program, and if possible, I'd like to have the credentials of this account to be encoded in the program, without ever logging off/out.

Is this type of access achievable using the MSAL or ADAL authentication methods promoted in the samples?

Thank you for all your help in advance

Comment: If it helps, the reason for this question is that I am trying to migrate a program using the EWS Managed Api to use the Graph Api instead, and the old program has these credentials encoded into the program.

Answer (score 1):

There are two methods of handling this, which you choose depends on your scenario.

**Refresh Tokens**:
Using Refresh Tokens you can ask for the user to authenticated once and then continuously refresh that access token. For scenarios where the user isn't always online/interactive, this typically involves a background process that automatically retrieves and stores the most recent token for the user.

**Application Only**:
There are several permission scopes that can be used without a `user` authenticating. Rather than logging in the user, the tenant administrator authorizes your application. Note that not all Graph features are accessible this way and there are certainly security considerations to keep in mind if you're planning to provide this to other organizations (i.e. expect a conversation with IT before they say "sure, have access too everything").

A couple of links that might help you get started:

- [Microsoft v2 Endpoint Primer](http://massivescale.com/microsoft-v2-endpoint-primer/) - primer a wrote a while back that walks you through how v2 authentication works (including refresh tokens)
- [v2 Endpoint & Admin Consent](http://massivescale.com/microsoft-v2-endpoint-admin-consent/) - an addendum to the above primer with details on how to implement Admin Consent. This would be required if you choose to with App Only.
- [Get Access without a User](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_service) - Walkthrough on how to implement App Only scenarios.

As an aside, you never want to bake credentials into your application code. This is one of the single biggest mistakes an developer can make as it makes obtaining high-level access to your systems and data downright trivial for bad actors. While OAUTH takes more time to setup and configure, it is **always** worth the investment.